# Launching a python script after another program (Unity3D) is closed

Tags: python, python-3.x, unity-game-engine

I have written a script on python for unity applications (on Windows) to parse through logs. It just opens .log files, goes through it and creates new ones. I need to launch it after unity application is closed. There is the easiest way to make it work just by launching it manually after you've closed the Unity, but is there any way to automate that process and make the script start after Unity process is terminated? And if so - how? It's a simple console application that doesn't require any input, all that is needed is just to run it.

```
import glob
import os
import time
import re
import getpass

user = getpass.getuser()

def exception_search(full_line):                                                                #Parsing function, that will filter original log file
    nonfiltered = full_line.split('\n')                                                         #Spliting file contents to have it as list separated by each line from file
    result = ["List of exceptions:"]                                                            #first line
    i = 0                                                                                       #index which will be used in for loop to iterate through string list
    previous_exc = []                                                                           #Will contain previous found exception to avoid printing the same one
    current_exc = []                                                                            #Will contain current exception to compare it 
    repeat = 0                                                                                  #repeating count that will be used to type how many times exception was repeated in a row
    for i in range(len(nonfiltered) - 1):                                                       #going through a range of array elements
        if "Exception:" in nonfiltered[i]:                                                      #Checking if we found an exception line
            #checking if element on top is not another exception, so, we would need to print it for context
            if (not "(Filename: <" in nonfiltered[i - 2]) and (not "(Filename: currently not" in nonfiltered[i - 2]):
                result.append(nonfiltered[i - 3])
                result.append(nonfiltered[i - 2])
                result.append(nonfiltered[i - 1])
                previous_exc = []                                                               #Zeroing previous exception remembered because after printing nonexception we need to reset it
            while (not "(Filename: <" in nonfiltered[i]) and (not "(Filename: currently not" in nonfiltered[i]):
                current_exc.append(nonfiltered[i])                                              #Filling current exception list with exception lines until we reach the last line of it
                i += 1                                                                          #incrementing index because we are using non-for incrementation to go through elements
            current_exc.append(nonfiltered[i])                                                  #adding the last line and separator for visibility
            current_exc.append("")
            if previous_exc != current_exc:                                                     #checking if exception was the same as the last one, if it is - we don't need to print it but increment the count
                result.extend(current_exc)                                                      #Not the same so we add the exception to the resulting list
                previous_exc = current_exc[:]                                                   #Putting it as the previous exception in case it will be the same later
                if repeat != 0:                                                                 #If count wasn't 0, so, we got exception repeated and we inform about it the reader
                    result.append("It was repeated " + str(repeat) + " times")
                    result.append("")
                    repeat = 0                                                                  #zeroing the counter after using it
                current_exc = []                                                                #zeroing the current exception for the next use
            else:                                                                               #exception is repeatig, so, we just summ up the count
                repeat += 1
                current_exc = []
    result = '\n'.join(result)                                                                  #Turning the list back into string with \n as separator
    return result

logpath = "C:\\Users\\" + user +"\\AppData\\LocalLow"                                           #Path where all logs are contained
text_files = glob.glob(logpath + "/**/Playe*.log", recursive = True)                            #Making a list of Player.log/Player-prev.log named files

for path in text_files:
    projname = re.match(r"(.+\\)(.+)(\\Player\-prev.log)", path)                                #Extracting the name of the project from the folder inside which log files are content
    if projname is None:
        projname = re.match(r"(.+\\)(.+)(\\Player.log)", path).group(2)
    else:
        projname = projname.group(2)
    #getting the last modified time of the log file
    lastmod = time.asctime(time.localtime(os.path.getmtime(path))).replace(":", "h ", 1).replace(":", "m ")
    filecontent = ""
    with open(path,'r', encoding="utf-8") as file:                                              #copying the contents of the original log file
        filecontent = file.read()
    newpath = 'C:\\Users\\' + user + '\\Desktop\\logs'
    if not os.path.isdir(newpath):                                                              #creating a directory for logs if it's not around
        os.mkdir(newpath)
    newpath = newpath + '\\'
    if not os.path.isdir(newpath + projname):                                                   #creating a directory for project if it's not around
        os.mkdir(newpath + projname)
    #getting a filepath for a log to check if it's already here
    filepath = os.path.join(newpath + projname, "full " + projname + " " + lastmod + ".log")
    if not os.path.isfile(filepath):                                                            #checking if log is not copied, if that's so, we are copying it by creating a new file
        with open(filepath,'x', encoding="utf-8") as file:
            temp = file.write(filecontent)
    filepath = filepath.replace("full ", "Exception ")
    filecontent = exception_search(filecontent)                                                 #parsing the contents of log file to get only neccesary exception lines
    if (not os.path.isfile(filepath)) and (len(filecontent) > 19):                              #checking if file is not created and there are exception which needed to be mentioned
        with open(filepath,'x', encoding="utf-8") as file:
            temp = file.write(filecontent)
```

Comment: I don't know your code but in general it would probably simply be `PathToUnity -someParameter; PathToYourPython "yourPythonscript"` .. could you maybe post your code and tag the question according to the used language?

Comment: For some reason Unity3d tag had bigger priority than Python3 listed with it. You are saying I should look up batch files and there should be a solution to this issue?

Comment: And I would need to write separate batch file for every unity application or there is a way to make a batch file that would work with any unity application?

Comment: You could pass in your project path as parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual also Unity when run via [Command Line](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html) only returns once it has exited.

So you can simply have a wrapper script like e.g. in batch (or whatever language you use)

```
C:\Path\To\Your\UnityInstall\Unity.exe -batchmode -username "name@example.edu.uk" -password "XXXXXXXXXXXXX" -serial "E3-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX" –quit -projectPath "C:\Path\To\Your\UnityProjectFolder" -logFile "C:\Path\ToWrite\The\Log\To"

C:\Path\To\Your\PythonInstall\Pyhton.exe C:\Path\To\Your\Script.py
```

---

You could also directly run your stuff from within Unity itself.

But then of course you would need to include that script into every project you want to use this way ;)

But yes, you can use [`[InitializeOnLoadMethod]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/InitializeOnLoadMethodAttribute.html) and [`Application.quitting`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-quitting.html)

```c#
public class test
{
    [InitializeOnLoadMethod]
    private static void Init()
    {
        Application.quitting += OnQuit;
    }

    private static void OnQuit()
    {
        var p = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = @"C:\PATH\TO\YOUR\PYTHONINSTALL\PYTHYON.exe",
                WorkingDirectory = @"C:\PATH\TO\YOUR\PYTHONINSTALL",
                Arguments = "C:\PATH\TO\YOUR\SCRIPT.py",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = false,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
            }
        };

        p.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unity returns only once because of arguments given in the command line when launching it or no matter how you launch it, if it's through command line you will only get return once?